# swift Failed with exit code 1 only when using phone as simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode10

After I upgraded to Xcode 10, when I tried to test my program using my phone as simulator, it asked for my keychain password....  I mistakenly hit the deny button and now when I use my phone to test, I get the code 1 error.  Even when using xCodes' Build function; if my phone is indicated as the simulator, it fails.  Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: "phone" and "simulator" are opposites; do you mean phone, or do you mean simulator?

Comment: Sorry, when I use the simulator, it works fine but when using my iPhone7 it no longer works.  Was fine till I did that deny...

Answer (score 0):

You can try restart and reconnect your device. 
If this does not help, you can follow [that instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202778):

> Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy. Now when
>   you connect to formerly trusted computers, the Trust alert will ask
>   you whether you trust that computer.

After that you will see the Allow request.

Comment: Thank you...  I did the reset, but I'm afraid it didn't work.  I also just downgraded back to  xCode 9.4, but that didn't help either...

Comment: I rebooted both my Mac and phone and that seemed to work along with your suggestion.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: If the question is solved, accept an answer or delete the question.